# Передача List в качестве параметра конструктора в Spring

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте. Такая ситуация: есть бин (не мной написанный, не переопределяемый), в конструктор которого передается `List` чего-то там. Насколько я знаю в `spring` при помощи тега `"list"` можно передавать массивы, но у меня вот такая ситуация. Что нужно передать? Именно List, а не массив? Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как поступить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<bean id="beanName" class="some.class"> 
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>2</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А Вы уверенны, что так в конструктор передастся именно List а не массив ? или spring сам разрулит эту ситуацию ?

Comment: А
>> <list>    
для чего?

Comment: У меня в некоторых случаях при помощи "list" сетается массив, а не коллекция.